# LIMIT in PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql, mybatis, postgresql-9.6

I have query written in Oracle in MyBatis Mapper xml file like below:

```
<select id="getUserList" resultMap="userListResult" parameterType="org.user.UserNumber>
   select * from user
   WHERE (1=1)
   <if test="num != null">AND rownum <= #{num}</if>
</select>
```

I need to make this Postgres Compliant. So, converted as below:

```
<select id="getUserList" resultMap="userListResult" parameterType="org.user.UserNumber>
   select * from user
   WHERE (1=1)
   <if test="num != null">AND LIMIT #{num}</if>
</select>
```

But it is not working and throwing exception:
PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near \"LIMIT\"\n

Can anyone help me please how to replace rownum here in Postgres?

Comment: remove the `AND` you also don't need the `where (1=1)`

Comment: If you want something both PostgreSQL and Oracle (12c+) compliant then `FETCH FIRST #{num} rows only`.

Comment: It worked. LIMIT should come outside and end of where clause. I had some other conditions in Where clause that's why I kept where clause,

Comment: If you use MyBatis' `<where>` tag you won't need the dummy `1=1` condition.